# Number Lemmas based on when they are referenced in text

Tags: cross-referencing, ref

I'm currently writing my thesis, and I have Lemmas in the main text as well as the appendix.

Lemmas are numbered based on their order in the text, therefore all Lemmas in the main text are numbered lower than those in the appendix. However some Lemmas in the appendix are referenced before some Lemmas in the main text are presented.

Therefore we have the occurances of whereby we reference Lemma 5 before we present Lemma 1. Ideally I would like to label the first discussed (referenced) Lemma as 1 and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: anything is possible but won't this be very confusing for your readers? I have never seen a document numbered that way.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My supervisor thinks that if we reference Lemma 6 (first appendix Lemma) in the text before Lemma 1 (presented in the main text) that Lemma 6 should be called Lemma 1 and Lemma 1 should be called Lemma 2.

Comment: Supervisors can be wrong:-) Different subject areas have different conventions so perhaps it's not wrong (have you seen any published works like that?) But certainly I have never seen that. Would you make the same rule for sections that if you have a forward reference to section 6 in the introduction, you renumber it to "section 1" even if it is the sixth section??? But as I say it is possible (although probably not exactly trivial to set up) if you really want that, someone will no doubt answer

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, they are certainly not infallible. If you think this is very much outside the norm I will relay such a message if it is brought up again. Thank you very much for your advice!

Comment: something that "may please both sides" is to put a stub lemma in the natural place in the document so it gets numbered in sequence and just have the text "details in appendix foo" or some such (depending why the lemma is in the appendix not the main text)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, that's a good idea! I considered such a thing myself, I will implement this.

Comment: You could also number the lemmas within their chapter, so that it's clearer where "Lemma A.1" comes from.  But that would involve something like "Lemma 2.3", which you may not like as much.

Comment: @Teepeemm -- it should also be possible when beginning the appendix to alter the numbering to prefix the numbers with "A", without altering the numbers in the main text.